# Google Civic Information API inconsistently returning NYC City Council Members

Tags: google-civic-information-api

I am working on an representative look up feature for my work's website. Everything is working fine, but we've noticed that when testing it out, some people's addresses are not returning their city council members.

I've checked out the normalized input field in the API response, and I do not spot anything that would prevent the city council member from being returned.

I tested out some addresses in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/civic-information/docs/v2/representatives/representativeInfoByAddress) here and noticed the issue there as well.

Has anyone else come across this issue with their local elected officials? I am wondering if I need to resort to using the Google Places Autocomplete API in order to submit an address consistent with what the civic info API is looking for.

Not sure what code I'd show to help solve the issue, but here is the request URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?key=${civicAPIKey}&address=${this.activeAddress}
```

Comment: I'm doing a similar project. All seems to work fine but not with addresses that are businesses or churches or similar non-residential addresses. In fact, today (9-26-22), no addresses are working and none work in the Google Civic API sandbox. This is really annoying because there doesn't seem to be a way to test the status of the Civic API. For my web application I'd like to test the status to be able to disable the function if it's down for maintenance.